# Inverse search jumps to wrong position

Tags: texstudio, forward-inverse-search, sumatrapdf

I have a problem regarding the inverse search in Texstudio. When Im doing the inverse search to find the corresponding code from the pdf, Texstudion always jumps to the wrong position. It is always the "next" section or chapter, but not to the actual one Im looking for. 
As an alternative pdf-viewer I have installed Sumatra. With the configured inverse search I get the same results. I also have checked that the filename is proper (no spaces and only "normal" charakters) and the path to the file follows the same rules.

Additionally I have includes a small example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, oneside,parskip,bibliography=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Testchapter 1}
    \blindtext
    \section{Testsection 1}
    \Blindtext
\chapter{Testchapter 2}
    \blindtext
    \section{Testsection 2}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

I hope you have some more ideas! Thanks

Comment: Probably an issue in synctex. Worked for me, when I use blank lines before the chapters / sections.

Comment: I have the same issue. The answer Tim mentioned, didn't work for me too. I'm using Texstudio's internal viewer and forward search is still working properly but not the inverse.

Comment: @Winsoft Same goes for me, I also used an external viewer (SumatraPDF) and there occurs the same problem.

Comment: @Martin I found a work around but probably wouldn't work for you. I am writing a conference paper and I commented all of the commands from conference template and now the inverse search works fine. When I uncomment them, again inverse search points to the last paragraph on the same page!

Answer (score 1):

I currently had the same problem. In my case, it was caused by the `bibliography=totoc`-option. I changed it by adding an option when creating the bibliography: `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]`, which has the same effect. (Supposes using biblatex.)